# Trim a text without loop

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, variable

input (in variable as $VAR) :

```
'yoo' : x'yoo' 'welcome' : x'welcome' 'we' : x'we' 'dum' : x'dum' 'test' : x'test' 'poo' : x'poo' 'D2-dog' : x'D2-dog' 'ant' : x'ant' 'rat' : x'rat' 'xmass' : x'xmass'
```

I want output as :

```
yoo welcome we dum test poo D2-dog ant rat xmass
```

I do not want output as :

```
yoo
welcome
we
dum
test
poo
D2-dog
ant
rat
xmass
```

I tried  `echo $VAR | sed "s/' : x'//g"` 
But it's messy and it's not what I am expecting.

Can we use `cut` or `tr` or `sed` ?

Edit after Alex answer:
I have problem with different text :

```
echo "'yoo' : x'yoo' 'welcome' : x'welcome' 'we' : x'we' 'test' : x'test' 'poo' : x'poo' 'dog' : x'dog' 'ant' : x'ant' 'rat' : x'rat' 'xmass' : x'xmass' 'exp' : x'exp' 'S-123': x'S-123' 'demo': x'demo' 'neu': x'neu'" | sed -e "s/'\([^']*\)' : x'\1'/\1/g"
```

I get output as

```
yoo welcome we test poo dog ant rat xmass exp 'S-123': x'S-123' 'demo': x'demo' 'neu': x'neu'
```

Strange and couldn't figure out the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed -e "s/'\([^']*\)' \?: x'\1'/\1/g"`

run like this:

```
$ MYVAR="'yoo' : x'yoo' 'welcome' : x'welcome' 'we' : x'we' 'dum' : x'dum' 'test' : x'test' 'poo' : x'poo' 'D2-dog' : x'D2-dog' 'ant' : x'ant' 'rat' : x'rat' 'xmass' : x'xmass'"
$ echo "$MYVAR" | sed -e "s/'\([^']*\)' \?: x'\1'/\1/g"
yoo welcome we dum test poo D2-dog ant rat xmass
```

This works, because `\X` back-references can also appear as part of the extended search pattern.

Edit: Changed RexExp to make the space before the colon optional

Comment: Thanks @Alex. But I have small problem when i try the same with following text, it wont work. `echo "'yoo' : x'yoo' 'welcome' : x'welcome' 'we' : x'we' 'test' : x'test' 'poo' : x'poo' 'dog' : x'dog' 'ant' : x'ant' 'rat' : x'rat' 'xmass' : x'xmass' 'exp' : x'exp' 'S-123': x'S-123' 'demo': x'demo' 'neu': x'neu'" | sed -e "s/'\([^']*\)' : x'\1'/\1/g"` I get out put as `yoo welcome we test poo dog ant rat xmass exp 'S-123': x'S-123' 'demo': x'demo' 'neu': x'neu'`. Not sure why it has problem from `'S-123'`. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: @Kasino: sometimes your input has a space before the colon. I changed the regexp to make the space in front of the colon optional. Try the new regexp